# Insert add video before main video with YouTube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have a page that displays YouTube videos using the YouTube API. For each video I have a specific 30 second add video that I would like to play before the main video. Is there a way to do this through the YouTube API or plain javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is embed the ad first, then when it's done playing, hide it and show the main video.

First, detect when the ad is done playing with the Youtube API [`player.getPlayerState()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status) function. This returns a zero when the video is ended.

Then, hide the embed with Javascript and show the main video.